# Why is my DataTables plugin not working at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've been trying to make the DataTables plugin work but I can't manage it. Here is the entire html code of my page. The apache server shows no error about not finding the css or js files. Here is my entire html code and the relevant js code since I have not really a clue where the problem might be.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap extra CSS -->
    <link href="DataTables/datatables.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/tutorial.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

     </head>

     <body>

      <div class="navbar">
      <div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">ASDB</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="background.html">Background</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown active">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Database access<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="form.html">Input Form</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="query.html">Query the database</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>
                        <li><a href="references.html">References</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="group">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dq" data-parent="#group">
                        Database queries
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#im" data-parent="#group">
                        IMs
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="collapse in" id="dq">
                            <h1>Database queries</h1>
                            <p>Have fun!!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="im">
                            <h1>IMs</h1>
                            <table id="ind-table" class="display"><thead><tr><th>IMs</th><th>Number of studies</th></tr></thead><tbody>
                            <tr><td>First IM</td>
                                <td>100</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="first_im"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Second IM</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="second_im"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                          
                            <tr><td>Third IM</td>
                                <td>153</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="third_im"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                          
                            </tbody></table>
                            <h3><button class="btn btn-default"><b>Visualize</b></button></h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>First IM: <a href="">Wikipedia Link</a></li>
                                <li>Second IM: <a href="">Wikipedia Link</a></li>
                                <li>Third IM: <a href="">Wikipedia Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables/datatables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/query.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

The code on query.js is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ind-table').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

After running this code my table is not getting any of the formatting that is supposed to come with DataTables. Am I missing something?

Comment: When the code is run, is the element with id `ind-table` available?

Comment: Yes, on the html code the only table available is defined as <table id="ind-table" class="display">. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Replace .dataTable to .DataTable();

Comment: I'm wondering if the ordering of the js files matter here but I changed them several times and there wasn't any difference.

Comment: @Atirag depends on what `js/query.js` is. If that's a different version of jquery, then you'll need to call `$.noConflict()` first before the code below.

Comment: No query.js is simple the DataTable code for the table ind-table that I showed on the post. Nothing else is there.

Comment: Try doing the same in a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put three `<th></th>` tags in the `<thead>` section. Then the problem will be solved

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>IMs</th>
    <th>Number of studies</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: @Atirag You need to put three `<th></th>` tag in the `<thead>` section. Then the problem will be solved

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! At least the format of the table changed although the ordering based on the second column didn't work.

Comment: Now it is working as expected. I thought the column numbers started at 1 but they start at 0 so I changed the query.js code to organize the table with respect to column 1 and not 2.

Comment: ya index starts from 0. Cool... Go ahead!!